# Массивы переменной длины и размер

Tags: c, массивы

Мне не удается найти однозначный ответ на один *мутный* вопрос. Я перерыл три **Стандарта**, десяток книг, у коллег поспрашивал, вопрос не прояснился.

Ситуация такая.

**Стандарты**, кажется все, запрещают объявлять массивы нулевого размера:

```
int arr[0];
```

Всякие расширения во внимание не берем. Как я понял, запрет на массивы нулевого размера был введен для того, чтобы сохранить одно из фундаментальных требований языка, согласно которому разные объекты должны иметь разные адреса.

Но что, если мы имеем функцию:

```
void f(const size_t _count)
{
    int arr[_count];
    // ...
}
```

В общем, вопросы такие:

1) Это уже неопределенное поведение?

2) Или неопределенное поведение возникнет в тот самый момент, когда функцию вызовут с нулевым параметром?

3) Или же неопределенное поведение возникнет лишь в том случае, если произойдет обращение к элементу массива переменной длины с нулем элементов?

Тема актуальная, потому что я видел множество кода, в котором стараются эффективно использовать стек, используя массивы переменной длины, которые могут оказаться нулевого размера, но при этом не будут использоваться. Как пример - функция взаимодействия с промышленным оборудованием, в которой имеется несколько десятков массивов-буферов.

Конечно, в таких функциях можно использовать **malloc()**, но это очень дорого по времени.

Так же можно использовать **int a[MAX_A]**, но это очень дорого по памяти - каждый вызов такой функции будет откусывать от стека огромный кусок, 99% которого не будет востребовано.

Comment: Не по вопросу комментарий, но на будущее. Не нужно указывать язык в заголовке. Он и так автоматически подставится, т.к. у вас метка языка [tag:c] стоит (:

Comment: Даже с указанным в заголовке языком мне постоянно предлагают использовать *самые крутые* фичи C++, хотя вопрос относится к C.

Comment: Ну, это проблема отвечающих)

Comment: @Максим узнайте о alloca и никаких проблем

Comment: @KoVadim, alloca() использовать не рекомендуется, потому что эта функция имеет специфичные тонкости, которые запросто могут стать причиной очень серьезных проблем.

Comment: Проверяйте значение `_count` перед операцией с VLA, чего проще то.. :) MSVC в базовом состоянии кстати не поддерживает VLA, так что вариантов кода будет минимум два, при кросс-платформенной сборке.

Comment: Пример: `int arr[((!_count) ? 1 : _count)];`

Comment: Понял, благодарю)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по [ответу](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9723093/1892060) из англоязычного СО, это неопределённое поведение. Там приводится пункт [стандарта](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.7.6.2§5:

> If  the  size  is  an  expression  that  is  not  an  integer  constant  expression:  if  it  occurs  in  a
>   declaration at function prototype scope, it is treated as if it were replaced by **`*`**; otherwise, each time it is evaluated it *shall* have a value greater than zero. (...)

То есть стандарт говорит, что выражение *должно* быть больше нуля.

Более того, Clang с UBSan'ом покажут, что это действительно UB:

```
vlazero.c:5:10: runtime error: variable length array bound evaluates to non-positive value 0
```

Comment: То есть неопределенное поведение как только функцию вызывают с нулем.

Comment: Да. Поэтому надо стараться проверять размер массива перед его объявлением.

Comment: Теперь все понятно. Просто в стандарте какая-то странная формулировка *не положительное значение ноль*. Я всегда считал, что ноль относится к положительным числам.

Answer (score 2):

Цитируя один из ваших вариантов:

"Неопределенное поведение возникнет в тот самый момент, когда функцию вызовут с нулевым параметром."

Разумеется, при условии, что управление попадет на ваше объявление массива.

"В тот самый момент", правда, не самая корректная формулировка. Неопределенное поведение не обязательно привязано к какому-то моменту. Правильнее сказать, что программа, содержащая вызов такой функции с нулевым аргументом, имеет неопределенное поведение. Компилятор имеет право на стадии компиляции распознать явный или потенциальный вызов, который приведет к объявлению массива нулевого размера, и отказаться компилировать код. Отказ от компиляции - допустимое проявление неопределенного поведения.